# Find the generating function for sequence $1,2,4,0,8,24,120,184,312,56,568,1592,...$

Tags: sequences-and-series, generating-functions

I'm having trouble finding a generating function for the sequence that has a closed form. The sequence can be deduced using two powers, with alternating negative and multiples of three as shown:

first term:
$1=1$

second term:
$2=1+2^{0}$

third term:
$4=1+2^{0}+2^{1}$

fourth term:
$0=1+2^{0}+2^{1}-2^{2}$

...

n-th term:
$n = 1+2^{0}+2^{1}-2^{2}+2^{3}+2^{4}+3(2^{5})+2^{6}+2^{7}-2^{8}+...$

Therefore, the -1 appears at every $4(mod6)$ term and the 3 appears at every $1(mod6)$ term greater than 1.

So I can construct the n-th ($n>1$) term as follows:

$f(n) = 1+\sum_{i=2}^{n}2^{i-2}u(i)$

where

$u(i)=-1$, if $i\equiv4(mod6)$

$u(i)=3$, if $i\equiv1(mod6)$

$u(i)=1$, otherwise

Is there a way to get a closed form of the function $f(n)$?

Comment: Hi @Joseph, i'm just curious, where do such problems arise ?

Comment: @AhmadBazzi this arises from my study of the Collatz Conjecture problem. It's related in a way to guessing the subsequent number in one of the two Collatz operations. If you're still interested send me an email joeschmidt97@gmail.com

Answer (score 3):

$f(n)=2^{n-1}-2^{\lfloor\frac {n}6\rfloor+5}+2^{6\lfloor\frac {n+3}6\rfloor+2},$ which only works for $n\ge 7$.

Comment: how did you know ?  trial and error ?

Comment: I fixed it. It should be right now.

Comment: Also what I did was that I added two $2^k$ back where it's minus, and subtracted $2^k$ where there are two more. Then the rest forms a geometric sequence and the leftover are my 2nd and 3rd expression.

Comment: @abc... How did you do this? Can you explain how you got to this? And what places a limit on n having to be greater than or equal to 7?

Comment: @JosephSchmidt I saw that this is a geometric sequence if I add and subtract terms (I will add and subtract later to make sure it's balanced), then it becomes the sum and differences of three geometric sequences, and since you already got the terms for $n\le7,$ it doesn't matter. Also, I checked it indeed work for $n\le7$ (I don't know why I put it there the first place) :)

Comment: @abc... thanks I get it now!

Answer (score 2):

Begin by finding the generating function for the sequence $2^0, 2^1, -2^2, 2^3, 2^4, 3 \cdot 2^5, 2^6, 2^7, -2^8, \dots$. This is the sum of 
\begin{align}
  \frac{1}{1-2x} &= 2^0 + 2^1x + 2^2x^2 + 2^3x^3 + 2^4x^4 + 2^5x^5 + \dots \\
-2\cdot\frac{(2x)^2}{1-(2x)^6} &= -2 \cdot 2^2x^2 - 2 \cdot 2^8x^8 - 2\cdot 2^{14}x^{14} - \dots \\
+2\cdot\frac{(2x)^5}{1-(2x)^6} &= 2 \cdot 2^5 x^5 + 2\cdot 2^{11}x^{11} + 2\cdot 2^{17}x^{17} + \dots.
\end{align}
Call this $g(x)$.

Then $1 + x \cdot g(x)$ will add the $1$ term at the beginning, which doesn't follow the pattern. Finally, multiplying by $\frac{1}{1-x}$ to get $$\frac{1+x \cdot g(x)}{1-x}$$ will give the generating function for this sequence's partial sums, which is what you want.

Comment: Why do you divide by 1-x in the last step? Also is there a way to extract what the coefficients are? The coefficients match the sequence, but I want to be able to determine the n-th term in the sequence.

Comment: There's always ways to extract the coefficients, but your question was about the generating function. (You can think of division by $1-x$ as a convolution with $\frac1{1-x} = 1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + \dotsb$.)

Comment: (The typical approach for extracting the coefficients is to take a partial fraction decomposition of the result, and then write each term as a geometric series.)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an idea:$$
-2^2 = 2^2-2\times 2^2$$ and $$3\times 2^5 = 2^5 + 2 \times 2^5.$$
So, for $n \ge 7$, we can split your sum as
$$f(n) = 1 + \sum_{i=0}^{n-2}2^i - 2\sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor\frac{n-4}{6}\rfloor}2^{6i+2} + 2\sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor\frac{n-7}{6}\rfloor}2^{6i+5}.$$
The last piece should be a matter of calculating these simpler sums.

Comment: Can you explain how you got to the last step? I'm a bit confused on that.

Comment: @JosephSchmidt instead of using a function $u(i)$, like you proposed, I wrote all terms as powers of $2$ or combinations of such powers. This lead to the extra sums that you see. What exactly is confusing you?

Comment: Nevermind I see what you did.